# What does ～ながらにして mean?

Tags: grammar

Can someone please explain the bold grammar?

> せんてんてき 【先天的】 《ダナ》生まれ**ながらにして**持っていること

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of ながら in this instance.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14189/use-of-%e3%81%aa%e3%81%8c%e3%82%89-in-this-instance)

Comment: Please try to use specific question titles.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose "生まれながらにして" almost always comes together, people rarely use only "~ながらにして" with othre nouns or conjugated verb from as long as my conscious life. https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%86%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8C%E3%82%89%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6
As the website above, "生まれながらにして" has more idiomatic sense as a whole.

It's an intriguing phrase, off the top of my head, "~ながら" itself is frequently used as a way of conveying the meaning 'doing something while doing something else', check out this http://www.e-japanese.jp/?p=291

–– Additional ––

So what is the sense of "して/にして" in "~ながらにして"? Well, I got the impression that it's almost the same meaning of 'even though/despite' in English.

Comment: When I searched [BCCWJ](http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon/), I found 67 examples of 生まれながらにして, 62 examples of 居ながらにして, 17 examples of 生きながらにして, 3 examples of 寝ながらにして, and a few other verbs with only one example each.